# How can I make paper minatures?

Tags: tools, miniatures

How can you take an images and easily (automatically) turn them into paper minis?

Comment: Are you wanting minis that are 2D or 3D?

Comment: Tokens or stand-ups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

S. John Ross [says he made Hexpaper and the first Sparks](http://www.io.com/~sjohn/faq.htm#Section%20C1%3a%20Fontmaking) set with Softy Fontmaker and now uses the [High-Logic](http://www.high-logic.com) product.

While they're not custom, there *are* a lot of nice paper minis in the [Sparks](http://www222.pair.com/sjohn/sparks.htm) sets, and several nice free collections.

Answer (score 5):

[TokenTool](http://www.rptools.net/index.php?page=tokentool), if you are looking to make your own tokens.

Using it, you can easily crop and resize images and then apply any number of borders (square/circle/oval).

I should note that TokenTool was written by a good friend of mine, @ColonelDork.  Despite that, I still recommend it. :)

Answer (score 3):

[World Works Games](http://www.worldworksgames.com/store/) sell images that are meant to made into what the website calls Standees. They are pre-designed cardboard minis in a number types and styles. You buy the PDF, print them out, cut them out and turn them into [instant NPCs](http://www.worldworksgames.com/store/products/coh1d20/coh1d20splash.jpg). They are $8 - $12 a PDF but after you buy it you can print as many as you like and if you are careful, they fold flat again, making storage a breeze. They work beautifully if you are nice to them, the only downside is a distinct lack of PCs.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use imagemagick.

I find an image on the net, crop it, and then run a [command](http://pastebin.com/n6YfNhmK) in imagemagick. (replace $1 with the filename.) For effective printing, it's trivial to then add multiple images to a sheet at a much higher resolution and print them out on heavy cardstock, as imagemagick can output to PDF.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered a company that has a standup-style custom paper miniatures maker that uses some of the advanced features of PDF files to do it without needing special software. Best of all, it's available free on RPGNow: Silvervine Games' [Paper Mini Maker](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=85950&it=1&SRC=newsletter&).

> With the Silvervine Games Paper Mini Maker, you can make miniatures from any image on your computer. […] All you have to do is open the PDF, click on one of the SVG logos and it prompts you to select the image. The PDF flips any image for you.

Of course, like all PDFs that do fancy dynamic stuff, it only works in Acrobat Reader, so 3rd party PDF viewers won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is an easy way but find some examples you like and use them as a template.

http://www.obsidianserpent.com/downloads.html

http://www.travellerrpg.com/images/Products/cco000_600.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I've built a free Paper Tokens Generator to easily create and print Monster Tokens for RPGs and Tabletop games. Have a look, feedback is appreciated. It's a work in progress project so there might be bugs and/or room for improvements.

https://paper-tokens.firebaseapp.com/